# how does first_value and last_value works with range unbounded preceding and current row?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions

```
select 
    empno,deptno,sal,hiredate,extract(year from hiredate),
    last_value(sal) over(partition by deptno order by extract(year from hiredate) )
from emp;

7782    10  2450    09-JUN-81   1981    5000
7839    10  5000    17-NOV-81   1981    5000
7934    10  1300    23-JAN-82   1982    1300
7369    20  800     17-DEC-80   1980    800
7566    20  2975    02-APR-81   1981    3000
7902    20  3000    03-DEC-81   1981    3000
7876    20  1100    23-MAY-87   1987    3000
7788    20  3000    19-APR-87   1987    3000
7900    30  950     03-DEC-81   1981    2850
7654    30  1250    28-SEP-81   1981    2850
7521    30  1250    22-FEB-81   1981    2850
7844    30  1500    08-SEP-81   1981    2850
7499    30  1600    20-FEB-81   1981    2850
7698    30  2850    01-MAY-81   1981    2850

select 
    empno,deptno,sal,hiredate,extract(year from hiredate),
    first_value(sal) over(partition by deptno order by extract(year from hiredate))
from emp;

7782    10  2450    09-JUN-81   1981    2450
7839    10  5000    17-NOV-81   1981    2450
7934    10  1300    23-JAN-82   1982    2450
7369    20  800     17-DEC-80   1980    800
7566    20  2975    02-APR-81   1981    800
7902    20  3000    03-DEC-81   1981    800
7876    20  1100    23-MAY-87   1987    800
7788    20  3000    19-APR-87   1987    800
7900    30  950     03-DEC-81   1981    950
7654    30  1250    28-SEP-81   1981    950
7521    30  1250    22-FEB-81   1981    950
7844    30  1500    08-SEP-81   1981    950
7499    30  1600    20-FEB-81   1981    950
7698    30  2850    01-MAY-81   1981    950
```

The `first_Value` function returns the first value in the ordered set. In the above example it returns the first salary value of each department.

But the `last_value` does not return the expected output which is it should return the `last_value` in the ordered set.  Here `last_value()` works differently by considering the last value with respect to the year(which is mentioned in the order by clause)

Why does it work differently?

Answer (score 2):

If you omit the windowing clause, it defaults to `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` in case of FIRST_VALUE and [LAST_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions085.htm#SQLRF00655) functions.

That means, for each record within a partition, the starting point of the window is the very first record. So, you get same value for all rows in 
FIRST_VALUE functions.

However, the end point is the current row itself, which keeps on changing for each row. So, you get the value of current row as the value for
LAST_VALUE function. But, if your ORDER BY clause is not enough to reliably identify the order, there will be a tie and the rows will be arbitrarily ordered, as in your example, especially for department 30.